# Chrome for iOS toggle between mobile and desktop

Tags: google-chrome

anyone knows if I can switch back to mobile version after requesting the desktop version in Chrome for iPhone. Basically in Android, you can toggle between mobile and desktop version. In my iPhone 4s, when I ticked the desktop version, I couldn't go back to mobile unless I open a new browser again. Any thoughts? I maybe looking at a feature that does not exist? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I have found that I can hit the Back arrow and that will take me back to the mobile version, otherwise right now, you can open a new tab, or look on the site for a link to the mobile version, which some sites offer. I agree, the toggle option should be a feature.